# Setting different Formatter config for each languages

Tags: localization, yii2

How can set different Formatter config for each languages? I'm using [yii2-localeurls](https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls) to language handler.

Like this for each language:

```
'formatter' => [
    'dateFormat' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
    'decimalSeparator' => ',',
    'thousandSeparator' => ' ',
    'currencyCode' => 'EUR',
```

],

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is to configure it in one place near the beginning of life cycle like common controller's init or module's init.

You can detect current language and based on this set all formatter attributes like

```
if (Yii::$app->language === 'de') {
    Yii::$app->formatter->dateFormat = 'dd.MM.yyyy';
}
```

Comment: That's a way. I'm looking for most suitable method. Thanks

Comment: [EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#EVENT_BEFORE_REQUEST-detail) is other way or [application init](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#init()-detail)

Comment: In [bootstrap](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-application.html#$bootstrap-detail)